# Вывести данные из 4-х таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

есть 4 таблицы:

```
+news--------------+news_tags--------+users--------------+tags----------+
|id                |news_id          |id                 |id            |
|name              |tag_id           |user_name          |name          |
|user_id           |                 |user_link          |              |
|add_date          |                 |                   |              |
```

нужно на странице тега получить все новости с этим тегом (например id 1) + к каждой новости все теги и данные юзера.

пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
SELECT f.id, f.name, f.add_date,
                            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.tag_id) as tid,
                            GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) as tags,
                            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.user_name) as user_name,
                            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.user_link) as user_link
                            
                           FROM news_tags
                           as g
                       LEFT JOIN news AS f ON (g.news_id = f.id)
                       LEFT JOIN users AS u ON (u.id = f.user_id)
                       LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON (t.id = g.tag_id)
                    WHERE  g.tag_id = 1
                           GROUP BY f.id
                           ORDER BY f.add_date DESC
```

вроде все работает, но получаю к каждой новости только один тег.
подскажите как правильно составить запрос и "правильно" ли так получать эти данные? спасибо!

Comment: *но получаю к каждой новости только один тег.* Нужно использовать 2 копии таблицы тегов - одна для выбора тем по заданному тегу, вторая для получения всех тегов выбранной новости. `FROM news JOIN tag t1 LEFT JOIN tag t2`

Comment: Хотя - мы ж выбираем по тегу, так что для выбранной темы хотя бы один тег существует. Значит, оба связывания INNER.

Comment: я бы выборку тегов отдельным запросом выполнил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите получить одним запросом, то нужно добавить еще 2 JOIN-а (для выборке по новости снова список тегов связанных и сами теги по связи).

Убрал лишние GROUP_CONCAT (они там не нужны, ведь автор у новости один).

tid возвращать нет смысла, когда отправляете запрос, Вы и так по нему ищите, значит в коде он есть.

И замените LEFT JOIN на INNER JOIN (если конечно у вас не может быть ситуации, что нет автора у новости).

```
SELECT
    f.id,
    f.`name`,
    f.add_date,
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT n2.name ) AS all_tags_for_news,
    t.`name` AS tag,
    u.user_name,
    u.user_link
FROM
    news_tags AS g
    INNER JOIN news AS f ON ( g.news_id = f.id )
    INNER JOIN news_tags AS g2 ON ( g2.news_id = f.id )
    INNER JOIN tags AS n2 ON ( g2.tag_id = n2.id )
    INNER JOIN `user` AS u ON ( u.id = f.user_id )
    INNER JOIN tags AS t ON ( t.id = g.tag_id ) 
WHERE
    g.tag_id = 1 
GROUP BY
    f.id 
ORDER BY
    f.add_date DESC
```